# Why is expanded container not visible within list view?

Tags: flutter

I have a widget that displays a 100x100 image and a blue container next to it which fills the rest of the `Row`.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(title)));
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
                child: Image.asset("assets/img_small.png"),
                width: 100,
                height: 100),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12), color: Colors.blue)
            )
          ],
        ),
      ));
}
```

This works fine but as soon as I use it within a list view, the blue container is not visible:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.separated(
      itemCount: list.length,
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
          Divider(color: Colors.grey, thickness: 2, height: 0, indent: 8),
      itemBuilder: (context, position) {
        return BlueBoxWidget(title: list[position]);
      });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am mostly interested why inside a listview the blue container doesn't try to expand its height as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue `Container` is there, but with **0 height**.

Try adding some height, like this, to get the container visible

```
Expanded(
  Container(
    height: 50, 
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12), 
    color: Colors.blue
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the `Expanded` widget that wrapped the `Container` it maybe work.